# Convert English URL to Spanish URL

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to convert English URL to Spanish URL. I have tried URL re-write management, but that does not help me. 
Following URL will show how to do URL re-write.

http://blog.beetleweb.com/2012/10/creating-custom-magento-url-rewrites/

My objective is to convert 
URL

```
www.example.com/customer/account/create
```

to

```
www.example.com/cliente/cuenta/crear
```

Do I have to create a new store for this, or this can be done without creating a store?

Comment: What is the use case for this ? Doesn't make sense to do localization like that , just add localization as one more resource /ln/customer/account/create or pass in query string

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There is not really such a thing as an English, or Spanish, URL. They are meant to be opaque identifiers: you query a web server for a resource, and get an HTTP response, that is all. That the characters of a URL spell an English or Spanish word is irrelevant.

Comment: @Raedwald: Actually this is the requirement of the client, and need to do this. So I just wanted to know whether it is possible to do it or not. Thanks

Comment: No client should be telling you the URL scheme to use. That is a technical decision. Find out why they want this and what they *really* need. Perhaps they just want resources available in both English and Spanish.

Comment: @Raedwald: They want spanish url because client lives in Argentina and she want her business to grow and she thinks spanish url will going to help users of Argentina to understand the website more easily

Comment: You can create a module for rewrite Magento core URL in `<frontend><routers>` in your `config.xml`

Comment: @Nolwennig: Thank you, can you please write the code for it, if it is possible for you. thanks in advance.

Comment: @AmukSaxena I post a beginnig of an answer for show code impacted, hope it help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Magento solution:

(the code below is not tested, it's just a beginning way of resolution)

> Create a custom module for rewrite Magento customer URL.
>
> In your `app/local/MyNameSpace/MyModule/etc/config.xml`, you can have
>   something like this :
>
> ```
> <frontend>
>     <routers>
>         <customer>
>             <use>standard</use>
>             <args>
>             <mynamespace_mymodule before="Mage_Customer">MyNameSpace_MyModule</mynamespace_mymodule>
>                 <frontName>cliente</frontName>
>             </args>
>         </customer>
>     </routers>
> <frontend>
> ```

### Apache2 solution :

(the code below is not tested, it's just a beginning way of resolution)

> Use Apache2 rewrite url rules, in `.htaccess` file in root directory for example.
>
> Your `.htaccess` file seems like something like this :
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteRule ^/customer/([a-z0-9\-]+)$ /cliente/$1 [L]
> ```